# Как получить значения столбцов в MySql?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

мне нужно записать в питон скрипт значения столбиков в mysql.
Я пробовал использовать этот код, чтобы хотябы(!) получить какой-то вывод в перменную row, но он записывал туда почему-то 1

```
with connection: 
cur = connection.cursor()
row = cur.execute("SELECT id,uid,money,nick FROM users WHERE nick = " + "'" + nick1 +"'")
```

Мне нужно получить каждое значение на строчке в разные переменные.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, это намного легче. Сначала получаем нужную строчку из нашей базы данных.

```
sql = connection.cursor() 
sql.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = " + "'" + userid1 +"'")
results = sql.fetchall()
```

После, получаем значения любого столбика на этой строке, к примеру id

```
results[0]["id"]
```

Answer (score 0):

а сама БД сохранена?
попробуйте через

```
import sqlite3; import pandas as pd
```

потом выгружайте саму базу

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("путь/к/вашей/базе/данных/база.db")
```

затем читаете ее

```
data = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM users", conn)
```

и смело можно выводить на экран,
в моем случае через

```
 print(data)
```